# Simple slide gallery effect issue. Slide only happens once

Tags: jquery, gallery, slide

Working demo [CLick](http://jsfiddle.net/seltjoek/VBnxg/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
$('span#pijlr, span#pijll').show();
$('#gallery').css('overflow','hidden');
$('span#pijlr').click(function(e) {
  if (!$('#gallcont').is(':animated')) {
    var slide = 490;
    var variable = $('#gallcont').css('left');
    var urechts = "-980px";
    if(variable > urechts) {
      $('#gallcont').animate({'left': '-=' +slide+ 'px'},'fast','linear');
    }
  }
});
$('span#pijll').click(function(e) {
  if (!$('#gallcont').is(':animated')) {
    var slide = 490;
    var variable = $('#gallcont').css('left');
    var ulinks = "0";
    if(variable < ulinks) {
      $('#gallcont').animate({'left': '+=' +slide+ 'px'},'fast','linear');
    }
  }
});
});
```

The problem is with the next button (span#pijlr). If i click once it wil do it's think, and will go too -490px but when i click again it doesn't do anything. I tried tweaking the variable urechts, but when i increase the number say about -1000px it wil work except that it go's beyond it's limits.

Comment: That's a really nice working demo you got there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your problem:

`if(variable > urechts) {`

`variable` and `urechts` are strings, you cannot compare them numerically.

Change the line(s) to something like this, using `parseInt` to get the numerical value:

`if(parseInt(variable) > parseInt(urechts)) {`

You could also change urechts/ulinks to be integers and only do parseInt once:

```
var urechts = "-980px";
if(parseInt(variable) > urechts) { ... }
```

Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/sVqNq/5/

***Edit***: It was pointed out that this doesn't work in Chrome.  This is because Chrome returns "auto" as the `left()` value the first time it is called if it wasn't explicitly defined.  Simply add `left: 0px` to the css for `.pol`.  Otherwise, you need to check for "auto" in your code.

Comment: That's strange, it works for me Tom. But what does parseint do with the value -980px does it convert it to -980?

Comment: `parseInt` takes the first integer it finds, so yes, -980.  If you don't use urechts for anything else, you could just define it to -980 and not have to call parseInt twice.

Comment: Tom, what didn't work?  I can page through all the slides in my jsfiddle example.

Comment: When I click PREV or NEXT nothing happens. Seltjoeks original code works though

Comment: Ok thanks, i was thinking why i just couldn't set "urechts = -980" and compare it then. It's because urechts is still a variable right?

Comment: Seltjoek, you could just set `urechts = -980` but `variable` would still be a string because `left` returns '0px' or '490px'.  In this case, you could do: `if(parseInt(variable) > urechts) {`

Comment: Tom, it looks like Chrome returns "auto" for `left()` the first time.  The easy fix is to define it in the css as "0px".  Fixed here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/sVqNq/5/

Comment: OK, example should be fixed.  Muffed it up a couple of times there.  This version is tested in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/sVqNq/5/

Comment: @JeffB Yeah, that was it :) Works like a charm now. Please edit your answer so that I can up-vote it :) You should add that Chrome fix if you haven't already Seltjoek